# React, Array of objects are unnecessary represented as DOM attribute when passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I have a custom functional react component 'list'
and I am passing huge list of the available rows as a props.

```
interface ListProps {
  rows?: Selectable[]; //| Observable<Selectable>;
}

const List = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ListProps>(function List(
  props: ListProps,
  ref: any
) {
}

List.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array,
};
export default withStyles(styles, { name: 'List' })(List);
```

Everything working fine, only one observation that makes me sad that all passed rows are represented additionally in DOM as an attribute.

[image]

I finding behavior odd, because it's obviously not required and can be handled as JavaScript reference by React. Any way to avoid that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share the body of the `List` component?

Comment: do you have any other attributes on that div?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko Thanks for the tip. Component is huge but when I have simplified content of the component problem is gone. So it's really props are just passed later as an attribute. I was wondering whether it's common behavior but apparently it's not.  You can mention this as an answer, so I will close it.

Comment: I've checked this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/div-rows-mveee?file=/src/App.js, React 16 strips the `rows` attribute from the dom, however it has not always been like this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html